# Installed Apache. Bash: 'service httpd status' does nothing,

Tags: apache-2.2, installation, httpd, service

I just installed Apache 2 on CentOS5 from source (httpd-2.2.15.tar.gz) using:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache
make
make install
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl start
```

I have verified that httpd is running in ps, and verified it is serving the default htdocs page. However, Apache is not found in 'service --status-all' and is not found in '/etc/init.d', so I cannot run 'service httpd status' or '/etc/init.d/httpd start', and other commands.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the pre-packaged apache2?

Answer (score 1):

`service httpd status` would only work on a pre-packaged apache install(i think). You are compiling by hand. There should be a `contrib` directory in apache source. look for an init script there. I think there is one for RedHat based systems.

Comment: Hmm, I may have to resort to the pre-packaged install. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - try `service apache2` instead of `service httpd`; found that works in most cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these return any results:

'service --status-all | grep httpd' or 'service --status-all | grep apache'

Thank you for your suggestion.